# What is the most user friendly projection mapping software?

Tags: software-recommendation, projector

I'm setting up a projection map for a non-profit that will have images projected onto angular and unusually shaped walls. I use modul8 on my mac in the past, but this case is different. They use PC (in fact their whole show runs off of a laptop) and they want the ability to change the images based on the theme of the show. They have an A/V guy, but I don't want to suggest complex software that is going to be hard for a beginner to use. What software should I recommend and then use to set up their show so they don't have to keep calling little old expensive me?

EDIT: I should also mention that this is a small non-profit, so free or really cheap would benefit them greatly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd hate to answer my own question, but just wanted to share what I found in case anyone else is interested.

PaintingWithLight has a feature rich demo that is very beginner friendly, and only costs a bit over $50 for a full license. Compared to other projection mapping software out there, this is an amazing bargain.

VPT 7 is completely free and feature rich, but not as intuitively user friendly. Luckly it comes with a pdf documentation with lots of pictures to walkthrough someone through every feature.

Dynamapper is a $5 app that also works, but requires some additional hardware (to connect a smartphone or tablet to a projector) and some 3d modeling experience.

Answer (score 1):

If the venue uses Christie Projectors; I believe the projection mapping development kit is free (for Christie Owners/Registered Units).

I owned 2 HD 10K-M Christies for a while; and the projection mapping always intrigued me.

The mapping capabilities are pretty incredible. Here is a sample video showing just how amazing the Christie Projection Mapping software (with compatible Christie Projector) is.

**AUDI PROJECTION MAPPING DEMO BY CHRISTIE**

LINK: [Christie Projection Mapping an Audi - DEMO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4sVTUAdoLg&list=PLvlGlsoR-zO9MHHLFe75GXQ1J8E_hC116&index=17)

Obviously, depending on the angles of your objects, you will likely need multiple projectors to do any sort of wrap arounds.

**Depending on the Venue**, they may stock Christie or more than likely Barco units. Barco may have similar software now for it's high end projectors.

Keep in mind the projectors that do this (at the time my HD-10K units were 60K USD each); are high end. You won't get the mapping capabilities with simple conference/media units.